# indent to next line in javascript

Tags: javascript, komodo

i am using komodo IDE 8.5

I am trying to indent to the next line to prevent code from extended really far to the right but everytime i just indent. it breaks the line and dose not register. I'm not quite sure how to word it.

example:

```
var price = 60;
if (price > 60)
    document.write("<p> the brown fox jumped into the cold river.</p>")
```

but i want it to look like this and still function :

```
var price = 60;
if (price > 60)
    document.write("<p> the brown fox jumped 
        into the cold river.</p>")
```

or something similar. when i just simply indent it breaks the line of code and de-colorizes it and shows it as not being correct.

how can i accomplish this? is it the IDE itself or do i need some kind of syntax to indicate what im doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to escape the new-line, with a back-slash:

```
var price = 60;
if (price > 60)
    document.write("<p> the brown fox jumped \
        into the cold river.</p>")
```

Note that, with this approach, the whitespace from the indentation will form part of your string. And it's also worth noting that, if your `if` statement spans multiple lines, its good practice to wrap the block with curly braces, if only for clarity when the code is reviewed and maintained, later, by yourself or others:

```
var price = 60;
if (price > 60) {
    document.write("<p> the brown fox jumped \
        into the cold river.</p>")
}
```

Comment: Usually HTML parsing brings this back to a single space in the browser, no?

Comment: Indeed, but but the length of the string itself, in JavaScript, will still include the indenting white-space.

Comment: That's 2 but's :). I guess it is down to preference if `+` or ``\`` is used then. Personally I would rather go for `"" + ""`... Or is there some kind of ad-hoc standard for this?

Comment: @owlstead: no, it's just preference (so far as I'm aware).

Answer (score 2):

You can't just put a newline in the middle of a quoted string in source code. You could concatenate the pieces, such as:

```
if (price > 60) {
    document.write("<p> thr brown fox jumped "
                 + "into the cold river.</p>");
}
```

Comment: +1 I prefer this approach over the accepted answer as it doesn't affect string.length